# protecting dockerhub login credentials in ansible playbook used in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkinsfile calls an ansible playbook module to login into dockerhub.

```
   docker_login:
    username: username
    password: mypasswordexample
```

What is a way I can hide the password in this playbook file as don't want it stored in scm this way.
Currently my jenkins job calls this playbook via a Jenkinsfile using this shell command
`sh "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansibleplayboook.yaml admin@serverip:/home/admin"`

I was thinking of using jenkins credentials but not sure how to inject and use in the jenkinsfile.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Brian

Comment: why not using ansible-vault ?

Comment: Thank you, Good idea. So I'm thinking encrypt the playbook.yml with ansible vault before I store it in scm and then decrypt it during the jenkins build. So far, I've created my ansible-vault credentials in jenkins, I'm just try to figure out the syntax now how to put it in a jenkinsfile to decrypt -getting closer to a solution.

Comment: You store the variables in a file, then encrypt the file with ansible vault, once done you include your variable file in your playbook.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.